# Return to scroll position when using django endless pagination

Tags: django, pagination

1) Initial load of list page shows 50 items.

2) By "clicking show more" using django endless pagination, there are 100 items on the page now.

3) follow link to 90th item in list and go to another page

4) click back button on the browser

The problem is that after step 4, the list contains only the first 50 items.The last 50 items is not displayed.

Is it possible to return to position of 90th item on list page by hitting the back button

Comment: Hi I am running to the same problem have you solved this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not special to Django. We can use url hash to return to specified place. So,

```
1. in html, code snippet <div id="test">...</div>
2. url like http://xxxx/#test will be located to div with id 'test'
```

But, this way cannot remember the exact position. 
For example, cannot remember position between two div each with an id.